# Add data from GET-request to table in HTML using ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs, get, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having trouble with adding rows to a table in my HTML, which comes from an array containing objects.

When I run my code I do a `$get` request like so:

```
var app = angular.module('TM', []);

app.controller('tableController', function($http){

    this.protocolList = [];

    // Initialise array 
    $http.get('../protocols').success(function(data) {
        console.log('Success ' + data);
        this.protocolList = data;
        angular.forEach(this.protocolList, function(value, key) {
              console.log(key + ': ' + value.id + ' - ' + value.name);
            });
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('Error ' + data)
    });
});
```

When I open up my web browser, I see the following:

[image]

My problems occure when I try to add this to a table in my HTML-file:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="c in tctrl.currentDataObject.tableColumns"> {{ c }} </th>
      </tr>

      </thead>

      <!-- This does not ouput anything...-->
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in tctrl.protocolList">
          <td> {{ value }} </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>

</table>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: How is your tableController referenced in your HTML file ?

Answer (score 1):

U don't need to inject $scope like this to get access to the DOM??

```
app.controller('tableController', function($scope,$http){
```

Im not sure if it is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example:

```
app.controller('tableController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.protocolList = [];

    // Initialise array 
    $http.get('../protocols').success(function(data) {
        console.log('Success ' + data);        
        $scope.protocolList = data;
    })
    .error(function(){
        console.log('Error ' + data)
    });
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="c in tctrl.currentDataObject.tableColumns"> {{ c }} </th>
      </tr>

      </thead>

      <!-- This does not ouput anything...-->
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in protocolList">
          <td> {{ item.id }} </td>
          <td> {{ item.name }} </td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
```

Comment: @Nilzone- I've edited my answer. Do you try to add the inject?? `['$http',..]`